# Why is changing password on user account is taking time?

Tags: linux-mint, password, administration, access-control, accounts

I have created a few accounts on my Linux Mint installation. A few of them have admin privileges. About 30 min ago I changed the password on one of the admin accounts using the `Users Settings` GUI. But I am still seeing the spinning circle. I have a few questions in that regard.

- How long do I need to wait to ensure that the password has changed?
- What will happen if I reboot the system while the GUI is still showing the spinning circle?
- I try to change passwords every so often. How do I speed up the process the next time?

Comment: In a normal situation, password changes may take a second. Not minutes. Something else is wrong. Is there a "OK" or "are you sure" window open **under** the user settings gui? Try minimizing the top-window to see.

Comment: It's possible your system believes that there is a directory services mechanism configured and is waiting for it to timeout.

Comment: Multiple admin accounts? As in, multiple accounts with a userid of 0 (zero)?. If so, you are asking for trouble.

Comment: @Bib not necessarily, they may simply have access to the `sudo` command for privilege escalation.

Comment: Trusting the GUI to represent when they system is finished with a process is sometimes problematic: there may be any number of reasons that your interface is stuck in the "spinning" mode.

Comment: @Thomas N, you missed the `?` mark. I was asking the question if this was so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How long do I need to wait to ensure that the password has changed?

You don't, this shouldn't happen, something is wrong with your system. Password change should be instantaneous. Inspecting `journalctl` logs could help you understand what's going on.

> What will happen if I reboot the system while the GUI is still showing the spinning circle?

If it's already taken so long, I am pretty sure some component has timed out/frozen and nothing bad will happen if you reboot.

> I try to change passwords every so often. How do I speed up the process the next time?

Do it from console using `passwd`.

Comment: I lack rep to up-vote. Marking it as accepted. Yeah, I think going forward, `passwd` is _the_ way to go.  Thanks!